# How can I display image in email layout on the laravel?

Tags: laravel, email, notifications, laravel-5.4

My code to send email like this :

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailMessage)
                ->subject('Test')
                ->markdown('vendor.mail.markdown.message', ['data' => $this->data]);
}
```

My message.blade view like this :

```
@component('mail::layout')
    {{-- Header --}}
    @slot('header')
        @component('mail::header', ['url' => config('app.url')])
            {{ config('app.name') }}
        @endcomponent
    @endslot

    {{-- Body --}}
    This is your logo 
    ![Some option text][logo]
    [logo]: {{asset('img/my-logo.png')}} "Logo"  

    {{-- Subcopy --}}
    @isset($subcopy)
        @slot('subcopy')
            @component('mail::subcopy')
                {{ $subcopy }}
            @endcomponent
        @endslot
    @endisset

    {{-- Footer --}}
    @slot('footer')
        @component('mail::footer')
            &copy; {{ date('Y') }} {{ config('app.name') }}. All rights reserved.
        @endcomponent
    @endslot
@endcomponent
```

It success send email, but the contain of email like this :

```
This is your logo 
![Some option text][logo]

[logo]: http://myshop.dev/img/my-logo.png "Logo"
```

The image not display

How can I solve this problem?

I follow this reference : https://medium.com/@adnanxteam/how-to-customize-laravel-5-4-notification-email-templates-header-and-footer-158b1c7cc1c

Comment: Laravel documents shows that it does not have an email component for images. You will most likely have to make your own.

Comment: @Stuart Murphy, What do you mean? Try to answer in more detail

Comment: are you sending email from local?

Comment: @Ashish Patel, Yes. I sending email from local

Comment: okay then make your app live.  and then follow @sletheren's steps.

Comment: @Ashish Patel, There exist error : `Undefined variable: message`

Comment: or convert your image in base64      <img src="data:image/png;base64,{{base64_encode(file_get_contents(resource_path('img/email/logo.png')))}}" alt="">

Comment: it's an example. give origional path there.

Comment: @Ashish Patel, There exist error : `Call to undefined function file_get_contents‌​()`

Comment: @SuccessMan check the path you are giving is correct or not.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me !

```
<img src="{{$message->embed(asset('images/image_name.png'))}}">
```

for those who have **Undefined variable: message** :
you need to send the variable `$message` to the view, while `$message` is the ***Mailable*** instance. 
example:

```
$this->view('view_name_here')
     ->with(['message' => $this])
     ->subject("Hello..");
```

Comment: +1 for the note about `$message`. The documentation says "Remember, Laravel automatically makes the $message variable available to all of your e-mail views" which is not true at least when using a `Notification` versus a `Mailable`.

Comment: Be careful with this method, in my case PHP (7.2) is returning "Fatal error: Allowed memory size exhausted error".

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question but this might help someone else. Try this... (assuming you want to replace the app name with your logo)

```
@component('mail::layout')
    {{-- Header --}}
    @slot('header')
        @component('mail::header', ['url' => config('app.url')])
            <img src="{{ asset('img/my-logo.png') }}" alt="{{ config('app.name') }} Logo">
        @endcomponent
    @endslot

    {{-- Body --}}
    {{ $slot }}

    {{-- Subcopy --}}
    @isset($subcopy)
        @slot('subcopy')
            @component('mail::subcopy')
                {{ $subcopy }}
            @endcomponent
        @endslot
    @endisset

    {{-- Footer --}}
    @slot('footer')
        @component('mail::footer')
            © {{ date('Y') }} {{ config('app.name') }}. @lang('All rights reserved.')
        @endcomponent
    @endslot
@endcomponent
```

When you extend `'vendor.mail.markdown.message'` you explicitly say that the rendered mail will use this view only, which is markdown, and you completely ignore the HTML email that'll be sent.

Markdown emails have an HTML version and a raw text version, you don't see the changes you made to the markdown files because you're looking at the HTML version of your email, so see those changes you have to update `/resources/views/vendor/mail/html/message.blade.php` not only the markdown one.

Answer (score 1):

```
@component('mail::layout')
    {{-- Header --}}
    @slot('header')
        @component('mail::header', ['url' => config('app.url')])
            {{ config('app.name') }}
        @endcomponent
    @endslot

    {{-- Body --}}
    This is your logo 
    ![Some option text][logo]
    [logo]: <img src="{{url('/img/my-logo.png')}}" style="height: 100px;"/>  "Logo"  

    {{-- Subcopy --}}
    @isset($subcopy)
        @slot('subcopy')
            @component('mail::subcopy')
                {{ $subcopy }}
            @endcomponent
        @endslot
    @endisset

    {{-- Footer --}}
    @slot('footer')
        @component('mail::footer')
            &copy; {{ date('Y') }} {{ config('app.name') }}. All rights reserved.
        @endcomponent
    @endslot
@endcomponent
```

See I have added an  tag where your image should be. The *url('/img/my-logo.png')* converts to your full site address where the image is stored.

Answer (score 0):

Try to output the image inside an `<img>` tag:

```
<img src="{{ $message->embed(asset('img/my-logo.png')) }}" alt="alt here">
```

Comment: It's the same. The result like this : `<img src="http://myshop.dev/img/my-logo.png" alt="alt here"> `. I use : https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mail. Seems it's different

Comment: how about using laravel's embed method? check the edited answer

Comment: it sould be passed: `Note: A $message variable is always passed to e-mail views, and allows the inline embedding of attachments. So, you should avoid passing a message variable in your view payload`

Comment: I don't passing a message variable

Comment: If use laravel embed, then in toMail method like what?